# Why does my custom text message ringtone stop playing?

Tags: sms, notifications, ringtone, 8.1-update-1

Recently I've changed the ringtone for text messages for some of my contacts. The new ringtone has a playtime of 11 seconds. However, when I receive text messages, the ringtone stops playing after ~5 seconds (I think it stops, when the phone screen turns black again).

Is it somehow possible to get longer ringtones working? Or is it (for testing purposes) possible to set the time, a notification is shown by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation by the OS - the sound will always play as long as the toast notification is visible which even is under 5 seconds. Unfortunately you can't change that duration, even as the app developer.

However you can tap the toast notification and drag it a bit to the right as if you would discard it but don't release it. This way you can keep the notification visible and the sound will play up to the ringtone maximum of 30 seconds.

Comment: I doubt many people are going to sit there dragging their toast notifications back and forth just to listen to their ringtone :) Interesting piece of info, though.

Comment: People are weird ;-)

Comment: Funny fact, I just figured out: when the phone is inside a bag, it does not enable the screen and therefor doesn't stop playing the ringtone.

Comment: Yeah the screen not coming on i get (it does the same in your pocket) but the ringtone part is weird...